# Error de git luego de actualizar a macOS Sierra - missing xcrun

Tags: git, macos

Luego de actualizar mi OSX de `El Capitán` a la nueva versión `macOS Sierra`, me sale este error al tratar de ejecutar cualquier comando de git, por ejemplo, al ejecutar:

```
git status
```

Me aparece el siguiente error:

```
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
```

¿Alguna idea de qué puedo hacer al respecto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar `xcode-select --install`.

Aparecerá una ventana de Xcode a la que deberás darle click en `Instalar`, luego de eso deberás a que termine el proceso y ya podrás usar `git`de nuevo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[Respuesta original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32893412/command-line-tools-not-working-os-x-el-capitan-macos-sierra#answer-32894314)

Usuario original [cuadraman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/985998/cuadraman) del site en ingles.

Answer (score 0):

La [solución de Angel Angel](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/49139/250) es buena, pero a mí no me funcionaba porque me aparecía el siguiente mensaje de error:

[image: Error, el software no está disponible]

Básicamente, lo que está diciendo es que no puede encontrar el software o que no está disponible a través del servidor. En ese caso, lo que hay que hacer es instalarlo manualmente siguiendo estos pasos:

1. Navega a la [página de descargas para desarrolladores de Apple](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/).
2. Entra con tu Apple ID (o el usuario/contraseña que tengas para Apple Developer).
3. Descárgate el dmg más reciente de *Command Line Tools for Xcode*:
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
4. Instala el dmg (sigue las instrucciones en pantalla, esto puede tardar unos minutos).
5. Prueba de nuevo.

Answer (score 0):

Para mi ninguna de las soluciones anteriores funciono, lo que hice fue reiniciar xcode tools

```
xcode-select --reset
```

Saludos

Comment: Please translate to Spanish. Por favor traduce tu respuesta al español. Este sitio es en español. Saludos

Comment: A mi ninguna solucion me funciono sino esta: 

    "xcode-select --reset"

Que hace reset the xcode-tools obviamente
Buena suerte

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu aporte, pero te sugiero que edites la respuesta y la pongas en español, y no como un comentario, para que los usuarios en busca de la respuesta puedan encontrarla y entender fácilmente. Saludos

Comment: Listo, gracias por tu sugerencia